# Trouble manipulating a log expression

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

This question sort of follows on from question [Functions with logarithmic integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141681/functions-with-logarithmic-integrals). The book presents an example of integrating a function whose integral is logarithmic:
$$\int \frac{1}{4-3x} dx = -\frac{1}{3}\ln{|4 - 3x|} + K$$

$$= -\frac{1}{3}\ln{A|4 - 3x|}$$

$$= \frac{1}{3}\ln{\frac{A}{|4 - 3x|}}$$

I'm having trouble seeing how the final step is reached. My approach is to separate the logarithm of the product to the addition of separate logs then distribute the minus:

$$-\frac{1}{3}\ln{A|4 - 3x|} = -\frac{1}{3}(\ln{A} + \ln{|4 - 3x|}) = \frac{1}{3}(-\ln{A} - \ln{|4 - 3x|})$$

The I use the property that log minus another log is the log of the first divided by the second to get this:

$$\frac{1}{3}(-\ln{\frac{A}{|4-3x|}})$$

But I still have a minus that the example in the book doesn't have. Could someone help me with this please? *Apologies for asking another question so soon.*

Comment: what does $lnA[4-3*x]$ means?can you determine by words?is it product of A and  4-3*x?

Comment: It could be the case that A in the second step and the final step are not the same. But because it's an integration constant, it is kept as is. So the answer is 1/3*C/|4-3x| where C = 1/A. More like K = + 1/3*ln(A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $-\dfrac{1}{3}\ln \left( A\left\vert 4-3x\right\vert \right) $ we don't
get $\dfrac{1}{3}\ln \frac{A}{\left\vert 4-3x\right\vert }$, because 
$$\begin{equation*}
-\frac{1}{3}\ln \left( A\left\vert 4-3x\right\vert \right) \neq \frac{1}{3}
\ln \frac{A}{\left\vert 4-3x\right\vert }.
\end{equation*}$$
However if we write the constant of integration $C$ as $C=\frac{1}{3}\ln A$, we get the final result, as follows:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{4-3x}dx &=&-\frac{1}{3}\ln \left\vert 4-3x\right\vert +C \\
&=&-\frac{1}{3}\ln \left\vert 4-3x\right\vert +\frac{1}{3}\ln A \\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\left( -\ln \left\vert 4-3x\right\vert +\ln A\right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\ln \frac{A}{\left\vert 4-3x\right\vert }.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: right because last one is equal to  $1/3ln(A)-1/3ln(4-3*x)$ and by using rule of logarithms substraction,great answer @Américo Tavares

Comment: @dato: Thanks. Yes, by the quotient rule (or subtraction rule).

Comment: @AmericoTaveres may i ask one question?can i   use this site http://problemasteoremas.wordpress.com/ in english language?because i dont know unfortunately spain

Comment: @dato My blog http://problemasteoremas.wordpress.com has only a few posts in English (search for the 'Math' tag). It is mainly in Portuguese.

Comment: ok thanks @ Américo Tavares

Comment: @dato You are welcome.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: Thank you for the answer. I think it's a little sloppy of the book authors to say $-\frac{1}{3}\ln{A|4 - 3x|} = \frac{1}{3}\ln{\frac{A}{|4 - 3x|}}$ (as it doesn't) but they probably assumed that the reader would know that the constant can be written in whatever form we want.

Comment: @PeteUK Yor are welcome! It may well be that.

Answer (score 0):

generally it would be clear that this one

$$\int \frac{1}{4-3x} dx = -\frac{1}{3}\ln{|4 - 3x|} + K$$
can be transformed  into

$-ln[4-3*x]+3*K$ 
or
$ln[1/(4-3*x)]+3*K$

i hope this would help you,you should know that  in case of  $a*ln(f(x))$,$a$ comes in place of power
Edited:
because i gave answer into different interpretation,let denoted $3*K=ln(A)$,so now by using multiplicatipn rule,$ln(1/(4-3*x))+ln(A)=ln(A/(4-3*x))$